# iPhone on a budget

Tags: iphone, wifi

My old iPod touch finally gave up the ghost after about 10 years. I would like to join Instagram and several other sites...but, living on social security, I can't afford a smart phone - it's not the phone it's the monthly service charge. So, my idea was to buy a used iPhone and use it wherever there is Wi-Fi for internet access.

Would this work? Also could I use something like Skype or some other Apple program to make calls or would it be internet only?

Answer (score 3):

If you want an iPhone without the phone, Apple recently updated the [iPod Touch](http://www.apple.com/ipod-touch/) with the internals of the iPhone 6. It still has only a 4-inch screen size, but with the updated hardware, it makes a decent iPhone without the phone. It costs $199 for the 16GB model, $249 for 32GB, $299 for 64GB, and $399 for 128GB.

Comment: And don't forget, you can FaceTime or iMessage, which is _almost_ as good as calling (unavailable in some territories).